# How to ignore Delayed Job query logging in development on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, delayed-job

How would I silence/ignore these Delayed Job query logs from log/development.log?

```
Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (1.0ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2013-11-19 19:55:45.053991', locked_by = 'host:desktop-virtual pid:22277' WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-11-19 19:55:45.053435' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-11-19 15:55:45.053519') OR locked_by = 'host:desktop-virtual pid:22277') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (1.4ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2013-11-19 19:55:50.056977', locked_by = 'host:desktop-virtual pid:22277' WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-11-19 19:55:50.056484' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-11-19 15:55:50.056530') OR locked_by = 'host:desktop-virtual pid:22277') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
```

I've tried adding this to `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb` and it routes everything but the interval query logs which still get put in `log/development.log`.

```
if Rails.env == "development"
  Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, "log", "delayed_job.log"))
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

The log line still shows up because that line is logged by ActiveRecord, not Delayed Job. See the [github bug report](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/477) for more info on that. Here's a workaround:

in `config/initializers/delayed_job_silencer.rb`:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  module Delayed
    module Backend
      module ActiveRecord
        class Job
          class << self
            alias_method :reserve_original, :reserve
            def reserve(worker, max_run_time = Worker.max_run_time)
              previous_level = ::ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level
              ::ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::WARN if previous_level < Logger::WARN
              value = reserve_original(worker, max_run_time)
              ::ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = previous_level
              value
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy It sure does. It hides all the `Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job` entries in your log.

Comment: This solution is too aggressive , delayed jobs won't print many other messages.

Comment: Works for me on Rails 3 and DJ 4. Actually it is not about the Rails version, its about the DJ version, as long as you have the reserve method in the Job class, this code simply masks it, disabling AR logging and enabling it again around the original implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Change ActiveRecord log level only for Delayed job. 
This will allow you to see other ActiveRecord logs.

Use:

```
Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job.logger.level = 1
```

Comment: If you have any other logging info from your job processing (emails being sent for example), you won't see it if you change the log level to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set log level to one as follows in the initializers. It helps me to ignoring delayed job query info from the production as well as development log too.

> ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 1